# Unable to build MySQL++ library

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql++

I'm trying to build [MySQL++](http://www.tangentsoft.net/mysql++/) libraries via Visual Studio 2013 (MSVC-12.0). I've downloaded "mysql++-3.2.1.tar.gz" and unpack it. Then I added "mysql-connector-c-6.1.3-win32\include\" path to the include paths and "mysql-connector-c-6.1.3-win32\lib\" path to the libraries paths for the mysqlpp project in the mysql++ solution and tried to build it:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol mysql_thread_init
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol mysql_num_rows
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol mysql_num_fields
etc
```

What else should I link to this project? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Those symbols are from the mysql client library, which is not included in mysql++.

Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies needs libmysql.lib

Comment: how about Configuration Properties -> Linked -> Input -> Additional Library Directories, I used c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib

Comment: the only other thing I can think of is maybe your build environment is mixing different versions of the mysql connector, so your mysql.h header and libmysqllib library are from a different mysql version?  environmental problems on windows can be maddening...

Comment: something that has bitten me before is Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library, make sure all your code is compiled the same, I used Multi-threaded DLL (/MD).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you used x64,but lib is win32

Comment: Please expand on your answer.